# Username and password not saving

Tags: php

i'm a PHP begginer. I'm actually trying to make a simple login system. I did it, but only for one page... Like you login then you go to index, it works... If i want to go to another page it requires me again to login. I've tried to make the form like this:

```
<form action="index.php" action="stats.php" method="post">
```

The both classes have the method POST. I've tried to double the form too like:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<form action="stats.php" method="post">
```

It still doesn't work.

Comment: How do you check for a logged-in user in server-side code?  How do you persist that state across multiple pages?

Comment: why do you want form with 2 actions ..

Comment: Do some searching around "PHP sessions", so your application can remember its state across various page views.

Comment: why you are using two actions page. Form action can have only one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to have

```
session_start();
```

on every page you need to check if the user is logged in

Then at the page that you decide if the credentials are correct you need to set a session variable eg.

```
$_SESSION['UserIsLoggedIn'] = true;
$_SESSION['UserId'] = $userid;
```

It is good to create a function that will tell you if the user is logged in

```
function UserIsLoggedIn(){
 if (isset($_SESSION['UserIsLoggedIn']) && $_SESSION['UserIsLoggedIn'])
    return true;
 else 
    return false;
}
```

So every time you need to check if the user is logged in you should check the following

```
if (UserIsLoggedIn()) { ... }
```

Comment: I'll try this, but i think it will work. Thanks so much!

Comment: Do not forget to set the session variable UserIsLoggedIn to false when the user logs out. and the session_start() must be executed before you print anything else out (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)